# Mass-Update Form w/VBA & SQL - ID not pulling correctly, records not being written to temp table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

**Edited since original posting:  I realized that I had declared the volId variable as an Integer, but it's being read as a string.  Once I changed the declaration to "Dim volId As String" the SQL code appears to be getting generated properly.  Now I just need help in figuring out why the records are not being inserted into the temporary table.**

I am trying to create a form that will allow the user to create multiple work records without having to re-enter the date, hours, and category information.  (Ex: 10 people worked the same shift at the holiday party.)  The way I plan to do this is to create a temp table, write a complete record to the table for each volunteer selected, then do an INSERT query to select everything from the temp table and insert the records into the real Work_Records table.  *(This second portion is not done yet.  I'm debugging as I go, and have gotten stuck with the first part.)*

The problem is that my records do not appear to actually be getting inserted into the temp table.  I'm guessing that something is wrong with my SQL code.

Thanks!

My code:

```
Private Sub qryAppendMassWorkRecords_Click()

On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.RunSQL "DROP TABLE Tmp"

'Declare Vars
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rstRecords As Recordset
Dim dynamicSQL As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim hrsWorked As Integer
Dim DateWorked As Date
Dim pgmWorked As Integer
Dim volId As String

'Set initial values
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryTempAppendTable")

'Create new temp table to hold values from the form
strSQL = "CREATE TABLE Tmp (VolunteerID VARCHAR(20), DateWorked DATETIME, HoursWorked INT, WorkCategory INT);"
db.Execute strSQL

'Grab the values for the static vars and assign them
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.Properties("Name") = "DateWorked" Then
        DateWorked = ctl.Value
    End If

    If ctl.Properties("Name") = "HoursWorked" Then
        hrsWorked = ctl.Value
    End If

    If ctl.Properties("Name") = "WorkCategory" Then
        pgmWorked = ctl.Value
    End If
Next ctl

'If combo box length > 0, create an INSERT statement to add the record to the temp table
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
        'Category is the only combo box other than the ones for volunteer names; make sure it's not getting picked up
        If ctl.Properties("Name") <> "WorkCategory" Then
            'Verify that the field contains a name
            If Len(ctl.Value) > 0 Then
                volId = ctl.Value
                'Reset the dynamicSQL to the initial code & add form values
                 dynamicSQL = "INSERT INTO Tmp VALUES (" _
                    & "'" & volId & "', #" & DateWorked & "#, " & hrsWorked & ", " & pgmWorked & ");"

                 db.Execute dynamicSQL
            End If
        End If
    End If
    qdf.SQL = dynamicSQL
Next ctl

DoCmd.OpenTable "Tmp", acViewPreview

End Sub
```

Comment: Why use ctl.Properties("Name"), not simply ctl.Name?

Comment: Because the example I based this on used ctl.Properties("Name").  I'd rather use ctl.Name if that's possible.  Thanks!

Comment: ctl.name and ctl.value are two main properties that can be accessed directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dynamicSQL = "INSERT INTO Tmp VALUES ('" _
  & volId & "', #" & DateWorked & "#, " & hrsWorked & ", " & pgmWorked & ");"
```

It will get a good Access SQL string:

```
INSERT INTO Tmp VALUES ('15', #12/02/2013#, 5, 3);
```

In Access Database, Datetime must be quoted with sharp #, like: #**mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss**#,
or #**yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**#...

```
#12/02/2013#
```

More your VolunteerID is a string, so single quote like this:

```
'15'
```

Please notify, Access can only execute one single "INSERT" instruction, not multiple INSERT's as in MySQL. If you have many records, you must do a loop using VBA.

And run it to insert into **Tmp**, that you have not done:

```
db.Execute dynamicSQL
```

For example, this worked for me:

```
Sub qryAppendMassWorkRecords_Click()

  On Error Resume Next
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim db

  'Set initial values
  Set db = CurrentDb

  strSQL = "CREATE TABLE Tmp (VolunteerID VARCHAR(20), DateWorked DATETIME, HoursWorked INT, WorkCategory INT);"
  db.Execute strSQL

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO Tmp VALUES ('242013', #12/2/2013#, 4, 39);"
  db.Execute strSQL

  DoCmd.OpenTable "Tmp", acViewPreview

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Here's my updated code:  
    dynamicSQL = "INSERT INTO Tmp VALUES (" _
                        & "'" & volId & "', #" & DateWorked & "#, " & hrsWorked & ", " & pgmWorked & ");"

The Immediate window shows the Access SQL string as INSERT INTO Tmp VALUES ('242013', #12/2/2013#, 4, 39);

Comment: Have you Tmp created in DB, and do you execute a single INSERT?

Comment: Unfortunately the records are still not being inserted.

I see your note about only being able to execute one single "INSERT" instruction.  I edited the code so that **db.Execute dynamicSQL** occurs immediately after the SQL statement is written.  That way it executes once for each SQL statement.  

The records still are not showing up in Tmp, though.

Comment: Then double click on Tmp to open it, does it exist?

Comment: Tmp is being created.  The last line of the code -  `DoCmd.OpenTable "Tmp", acViewNormal` - opens the table.  But the table is empty.

Comment: I closed the database and reopened it.  Everything is working perfectly now!  I do not have a clue why the table was opening as empty before and now shows the records...but I'm not going to argue with it.  Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: You can now not to use qryTempAppendTable by commenting.

Comment: +1 for a good effort. My only comment is that any time I see dynamic SQL constructing an Access date literal as `"#" & DateValue & "#"` I fear that some day someone will use that construct on a machine that has been configured to use `dd-mm-yyyy` date formatting and then later (sometimes months later) they wonder why their dates have been corrupted: e.g., April 2 mysteriously becomes February 4. Constructing Access date literals should **always** be something like `"#" & Format(DateValue, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"`.